# Rebuild index process is not showing on sys.dm_exec_requests table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I am currently rebuilding indexes of my table and it has been running for 7 hours. It occurred to me that the alter index process is not appear when I select into `sys.dm_exec_requests` table.

Please suggest what to do, if I were to cancel this reindex window what will happen?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another one for the "don't use the GUI" folder - hitting that "Script" button instead of "OK" will generate a script that you can run from a session whose SPID you know.  That said, I notice it says "Success" in the Status column. So maybe it's done?

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_requests.command` is not documented to contain `index` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 use `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` to get the actual running command. Also you need to be sysadmin to get info on other requests. Maybe check out this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139225/220697 for progress monitoring